# Can DLL be used with Windows Form applications

Tags: visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I DllExport a C++ Class for use in a C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741035/how-do-i-dllexport-a-c-class-for-use-in-a-c-application)

I want to use my functions in DLL files in Windows Form based Application. Is it possible and if yes, Then please post a suitable tutorial as i am getting the following error when trying to do so with one of the DIVIDE function in DLL:

..\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\MathFuncsDll\MathFuncsDll.h(19): error C3395: 'MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Divide' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

Comment: Have you tried simply not adding DllExport to those functions?

Answer (score 2):

In managed C++ (which I assume it is, since you are using __clrcall) you don't have to export functions for them to be visible. Anything made public (in a public class) is exported automatically, as in other .NET languages.

Comment: Actaually it is not like that. I created a DLL using win32 console application. It was working fine when i used in another console project under same solution. But when i tried to use the same DLL in new form based project, it is giving above error.

Comment: Are the console apps unmanaged? Are you getting the error when you #include the header file for the .dll into your forms app (which I asssume also is in C++)? In that case it is because a forms app is managed and the included header will be treated as managed.

Comment: No, I am getting the error when i'm trying to call the function of DLL from my Button_Clicked event. i created the same DLL given at following Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx