# Call C++ Dll in C#.net using dllImport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, call, dllimport

Please find the below Examples

```
void ExitLibrary(); // C++ function
```

I am able to covert to C# like below

```
[DllImport("VisualFOD.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void ExitLibrary();
```

This method will be used to start the live capturing

```
bool StartLive(DShowLib::Grabber* f_Grabber, HDC f_hHdc, RECT f_WindowRect);
```

This method will be used to start the live capturing

```
[DllImport("TIS_UDSHL09_vc71.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool StartLive(IntPtr f_Grabber, IntPtr f_hHdc, Rectangle f_WindowRect);
```

I am not able to access the actual class DShowLib::Grabber as mentioned in the 2nd statement C++ function.

Do you have any idea how to declare and get the library class name?

This dll is not a COM/.Net dll to include as a reference to C# environment.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741035/how-do-i-dllexport-a-c-class-for-use-in-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: This is not going to come to a good end.  You can tinker with DirectShow using the DirectShow.NET wrapper.  Type that in a google query, take the 2nd hit.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you won't be able to access the DShowLib::Grabber class directly in C# if it resides inside the DLL (and is accessed by a C++ header file).

Two solutions are available. Firstly, you can wrap the native DLL class in C++/CLI class, such that you can include the native C++ header files; Secondly, you can write your own DLL, where you can flatten the DLL class and P/Invoke your flatten methods.

By flattening I mean:

```
class C
{
    void M(int i, float j);
}
```

The method M has to be called like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall C_M(C * instance, int i, float j)
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
        return FALSE;

    instance->M(i, j);

    return TRUE;
}
```

However, please take into consideration comments for your question. If you can use ready-made wrapper for library you are interested in, you shall do so :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I will give a try and update you further.

Answer (score 0):

There were many attempts to make C#/C++ interop easier, but by far managed C++ from Microsoft is probably the best (though it is not part of C++ standard).

Another promising option is CXXI from Mono,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html

which provides a standard compliant approach.

It still needs some hacking (Google Summer of Code 2012 maybe), but it should finally support Visual C++ and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can instantiate and access a C++ class object directly from your own C# code via PInvoke, but it is very complicated and involves a lot of work, please go here and read what that C++ PInvoke Interop SDK can do.

http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk/

(It is a commercial software though. I am the author)