# EntryPointNotFoundException occurred while calling C++ function from C#

Tags: pinvoke, dllimport, dllexport

I wish to call C++ function (here Score()) which is present in Score_Update1.dll.
Both C# & C++ files get compiled successfully. I have also put above dll into the Debug/bin of C# project. But when I run C# code it gives EntryPointNotFoundException.
What could be the reason behind this Exception?
I tried dependency walker for Score_Update1.dll. But it doesn't show any Entry Point

I wish to use PInvoke technique for calling C++ function from C#

```
            // Score_Update1.h

            #pragma once

            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;
            using namespace System;
            extern "C"{
            #define MYAPI __declspec(dllexport) 


            namespace Score_Update1 {
                public class MYAPI UpdateScore
                {
                    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
                    public:
                         void Score();
                };
            }
            }


            // This is the main Score_Updat1.dll DLL file.

            #include "stdafx.h"

            #include "Score_Update1.h"
            using namespace Score_Update1;

            void UpdateScore::Score()
            {
                cout<<"Score has been updated";
            }
```

C# code is as follows:

```
            using Score_Update1;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

            namespace GameTesting
            {
                class Game
                {
                    [DllImport("Score_Update1.dll")]
                    internal extern static void Score();

                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Game.Score();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: probably you have to set calling convention: [DllImport("Score_Update1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

Comment: @Maher That member function uses [`__thiscall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `EntryPointNotFoundException` is that the DLL does not contain an entry point named `Score`. If you look at the exported names using dumpbin or some similar tool you will see mangled names.

However, using the mangled name isn't going to help you here. You've exported a class and the function you want to call is a member function. You cannot directly instantiate a C++ class from pinvoke. And you cannot call member functions. If you wish to use pinvoke you would need to flatten the class to a C style interface. Another route would be to compile the C++ code to a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly and consume that.

Comment: How to make C++ class as C style interface?
Can I access functions by doing it..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741035/how-do-i-dllexport-a-c-class-for-use-in-a-c-sharp-application