# Unity3D Project - Access functions and classes from .dylib file

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, wrapper, dylib

I am in the process of developing an app in Unity3D which will simulate the cycling experience. To gather data from bike I will use an [ANT+ sensor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Garmin-Cadence-Sensor-Forerunner-Montana/dp/B000BFNOT8/ref=pd_bxgy_diy_img_y) connected to my MacBook via wireless [USB stick](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00N7I2TTW/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d1_i4?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1CWMW76T904588SSV692&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455333147&pf_rd_i=468294).

My problem is to get the data received from sensor in Unity3D. On the developers website I've found all the [files](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Garmin-Cadence-Sensor-Forerunner-Montana/dp/B000BFNOT8/ref=pd_bxgy_diy_img_y) necessary to use their product.

When I look through the files I found out that all the libraries are written in C++. From what I've read in order to access those classes in Unity3D I have to create a wrapper from C++ to C#.

For me right now everything is a little unclear and I really don't know how should I start with this.

For now I have the library for sensor - .dylib file (with classes and functions in C++) which I know that I have to import it in my project but i have no idea how to access the content of it.

Can someone explain me how should I manage this problem and how can I create the wrapper and access the classes in Unity3D?

Comment: link for sensors' library : [sensor library](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_FR88ik2zNucFdVWDlJUFJkOW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741035/how-do-i-dllexport-a-c-class-for-use-in-a-c-sharp-application